# Simple Spring GraphQL Subscription returning error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql-java, spring-graphql

I'm trying to create a simple Spring GraphQL subscription handler. Here's my controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @QueryMapping
    String sayHello() {
        return "Hello!";
    }

    @SubscriptionMapping
    Flux<String> greeting(@Argument int count) {
        return Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(() -> "Hello @ " + Instant.now()))
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .take(count);
    }
}
```

Here's the GraphQL schema:

```
type Query {
    sayHello: String
}

type Subscription {
    greeting(count: Int): String
}
```

Spring configuration:

```
spring:
    graphql:
        graphiql:
            enabled: true
            path: /graphiql
```

When I try to run above subscription using graphiql hosted by the spring I receive following error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "isTrusted": true
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run the same graphql request using Postman I receive following response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "upstreamPublisher": {
            "scanAvailable": true,
            "prefetch": -1
        }
    }
}
```

What is causing the subscription not to return data from my controller?

Comment: Have you got any workaround for this? I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: No. In my case I went with using query with polling instead, but I added an [issue on spring-graphql for that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/issues/570)

Answer (score 3):

May be you missed to use websocket property in your application.properties files

###### Add given property

spring.graphql.websocket.path=/graphql

###### Also remember to add websocket dependency

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the linked GitHub issue, a subscription requires the ability to stream data within a persistent transport connection - this is not available other plain HTTP.

You'll need to [enable WebSocket support in your application first](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.graphql.transports.http-websocket). The GraphiQL UI should use the WebSocket transport transparently for this.